# RapidXML accessing sibling nodes causes segfaults for seemingly no reason

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

So I recently got a hold of RapidXML to use as a way to parse XML in my program, I have mainly been using it as a way to mess around but I have been getting some very weird issues that I'm really struggling to track down. Try and stick with me through this, because I was pretty thorough with trying to fix this issue, but I must be missing something.

First off here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <image key="tilemap_roguelikesheet" path="res/media/tilemaps/roguelikesheet.png" />
    <image key="tilemap_tiles" path="res/media/tilemaps/tiles.png" />
</resources>
```

The function the segfault occurs:

```
void TextureManager::LoadResource(const char* pathToFile)
{
    rapidxml::xml_document<>* resource = Resources::LoadResource(pathToFile);
    std::string imgName;
    std::string imgPath;

    if (resource != NULL)
    {
        rapidxml::xml_node<>* resourcesNode = resource->first_node("resources");

        if (resourcesNode != NULL)
        {
            for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* child = resourcesNode->first_node("image"); child; child = child->next_sibling())
            {
                //Crash here on the second loop through.
                imgName = child->first_attribute("key")->value();
                imgPath = child->first_attribute("path")->value();
                Astraeus::Log(moduleName, "Image Name: " + imgName);
                Astraeus::Log(moduleName, "Image Path: " + imgPath);

                TextureManager::AddTexture(imgName, imgPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Astraeus::Error(moduleName, "Resources node failed to load!");
        }

        resource->clear();

    }
    else
    {
        std::string fileName(pathToFile);
        Astraeus::Error(moduleName, fileName + " could not be loaded.");
    }
}
```

So segfault happens on the second loop of the for loop to go through all the nodes, and triggers when it tries to do the imgName assignment. Here's where things get a bit odd. When doing a debug of the program, the initial child nodes breakdown shows it has memory pointers to the next nodes and it's elements/attributes etc. When investigating those nodes, you can see that the values exist and rapidxml has seemingly successfully parsed the file.

However, when the second loop occurs, child is shown to still have the exact same memory pointers, but this time the breakdown in values show they are essentially NULL values, so the program fails and we get the code 139. If you try and look at the previous node, that we have just come from the values are also NULL.

Now say, I comment out the line that calls on the AddTexture function, the node is able to print out all the nodes values no problems at all. (The Log method is essentially just printing to console until I do some more funky stuff with it.) so the problem must lie in the function? Here it is:

```
void TextureManager::AddTexture(const std::string name, const std::string path)
{

    Astraeus::Log(moduleName, "Loading texture: " + path);
    if (texturesLookup.find(name) != texturesLookup.end())
    {
        Astraeus::Error(moduleName, "Texture Key: " + name + " already exists in map!");
    }
    else
    {

        texturesLookup.insert(std::make_pair(name, path));
        //Texture* texture = new Texture();

        /*if (texture->LoadFromFile(path))
        {
           //textures.insert(std::make_pair(name, texture));
        }
        else
        {
            Astraeus::Error(moduleName, "Failed to add texture " + name + " to TextureManager!");
        }*/
    }
}
```

Ignoring the fact that strings are passed through and so should not affect the nodes in any way, this function is still a bit iffy. If I comment out everything it can work, but sometimes just crashes out again. Some of the code got commented out because instead of directly adding the key name, plus a memory pointer to a texture, I switched to storing the key and path strings, then I could just load the texture in memory later on as a workaround. This solution worked for a little bit, but sure enough began to segfault all over again.

I can't really reliably replicate or narrow down what causes the issue everytime, so would appreciate any help. Is RapidXML doc somehow going out of scope or something and being deleted?

For the record the class is practically just static along with the map that stores the texture pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with that API you are using but be aware that the next sibling in most XML APIs I know can return any type of node and not only element nodes, so you are likely hitting the text node between the two elements.

Comment: RapidXML is slightly different in it's execution, in that next_sibling() does actually get the next proper node (in this case <image>) rather than treating the contents of an <image> node as it's own text node. If you wish to get the text from those, you have to call value() on the node (in my code that is child). I also debugged the node value, and so I know next_sibling() will call and can in fact see the next proper node, except when it loops, all those values nullify, to the point where, looking at the pointer to previous node, shows it value to be null.

Comment: Your `image` elements are empty but there are white space only text nodes between the `image` elements. Does your code work if you have e.g. `<resources><image key="tilemap_roguelikesheet" path="res/media/tilemaps/roguelikesheet.png" /><image key="tilemap_tiles" path="res/media/tilemaps/tiles.png" /></resources>`?

Comment: No, the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anybody coming back again in the future here's what was happening.

Yes, it was a scope issue but not for the xml_document as I kept initially thinking. The xml_file variable that was in the resources load function was going out of scope, which meant due to the way RapidXML stores things in memory, as soon as that goes out of scope then it frees up the memory, which led to the next time dynamic allocation happened by a specific function it would screw up the xml document and fill it with garbage data.

So I guess the best idea is to make sure xml_file and xml_document do not go out of scope. I have added some of the suggestions from previous answers, but I will point out those items WERE in the code, before being removed to help with the debug process.

Thanks everybody for the help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that Martin Honnen made the point.

If `next_sibling()` return the pointer to the text node between the two "image" elements, when you write

```
imgName = child->first_attribute("key")->value();
```

you obtain that `child->first_attribute("key")` is a null pointer, so the `->value()` is dereferencing a null pointer. Crash!

I suppose you should get the `next_sibling("image")` element; something like

```
for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* child = resourcesNode->first_node("image");
     child;
     child = child->next_sibling("image"))
```

And to be sure not to use a null pointer, I strongly suggest you to check the attribute pointers (are you **really sure** that "image" elements ever carry the "key" and the "path" elements?); something like this

```
         if ( child->first_attribute("key") )
            imgName = child->first_attribute("key")->value();
         else
            ;  // do something

         if ( child->first_attribute("path") )
            imgPath = child->first_attribute("path")->value();
         else
            ;  // do something
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It's fine with the English front, I get what you're saying. :) I replied to Martin above, but what I will say that I had attempted that before, the problem then becomes the for loop check to continue looping equates to true, so the next node never gets parsed properly. So it parses the first node, but not the second.

Comment: @ConnallLindsay - thanks about English front :) ; about segfault front ... well... I have no more ideas; but my suggestion about checking `first_attribute()` remain

Answer (score 0):

This line is setting my teeth on edge...

```
 rapidxml::xml_document<>* resource = Resources::LoadResource(pathToFile);
```

`LoadResource` returns a pointer, but you never free it anywhere...?

Are you 100% sure that function isn't returning a pointer to an object that's now gone out of scope. Like this classic bug...

```
int * buggy()
{
  int i= 42;
  return &i;   // UB
}
```

As @max66 says. You should use `next_sibling("image")`. If that's failing, you need to find out why.